# Angular Firestore Authentication not working on IE11

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, polyfills

Some of the methods of AngularFireAuth not working in IE11 (probably polyfill issues).
I got this message (for example):

```
"Object doesn't support property or method 'signInWithCustomToken'"
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try compatibility view as sometimes websites don't look or function like you expect them